# filter JSON data in nodejs

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

I am working on MEAN framework. I have JSON as show below:

```
[{
  "restaurant": {
    "_id": "55095363649e380e12cc1868",
    "name": "Skygarage"
  },
  "sumSP": 241
}, {
  "restaurant": {
    "_id": "54e6afe5c1184450416e3118",
    "name": "Farmaaish"
  },
  "sumSP": 3920
},{
  "restaurant": {
    "_id": "55095363649e380e12cc1868",
    "name": "Skygarage"
  },
  "sumSP": 2333
},{
  "restaurant": {
    "_id": "55095363649e380e12cc1868",
    "name": "Skygarage"
  },
  "sumSP": 2445
}]
```

I want to filter sumSP based on restaurant. such that for above example I need following filtered array:

```
    [{
      'Skygarage':[241,2333,2445]
     },
    {
      'Farmaaish':[3920]
    }]
```

I have seen solution with using _.where of lodash but this should need value of filtered property, but in my case I dont know how many restaurants will be there in my JSON.

Comment: Why do you need two different objects in the result, and why can't it be simply `{ Skygarage: [ 241, 2333, 2445 ], Farmaaish: [ 3920 ] }`?

Comment: even this will work. All I want is filtered data either in single object or as array of objects.

Comment: Have you used `Array.prototype.reduce` before?

Comment: No, I haven't used Array.prototype.reduce before

Comment: @zulekha to rephrase what @thefourtheye was saying, checkout  [`Array.prototype.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce). It MAY be what you are looking for _wink wink nudge nudge_.

Comment: Yes I am looking and trying it :)

Comment: I would have done it with `Array.prototype.reduce`, like [this](http://ideone.com/J9dqtV)

Comment: Thanks @thefourtheye :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way do to it with lodash:

```js
var data = [{
  "restaurant": {
    "_id": "55095363649e380e12cc1868",
    "name": "Skygarage"
  },
  "sumSP": 241
}, {
  "restaurant": {
    "_id": "54e6afe5c1184450416e3118",
    "name": "Farmaaish"
  },
  "sumSP": 3920
},{
  "restaurant": {
    "_id": "55095363649e380e12cc1868",
    "name": "Skygarage"
  },
  "sumSP": 2333
},{
  "restaurant": {
    "_id": "55095363649e380e12cc1868",
    "name": "Skygarage"
  },
  "sumSP": 2445
}];

var reduced = _.reduce(data, function (result, value, key) {
    console.log(result, value, key);
    if (!result[value.restaurant.name]) result[value.restaurant.name] = [];
    result[value.restaurant.name].push(value.sumSP);
    return result;
}, {});

document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = JSON.stringify(reduced);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/3.10.0/lodash.min.js"></script>
<pre id="result"></pre>
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, this also works what exactly I want.